# Node: Mocha TDD sending Array in body

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js, supertest

Below is the following body format I need to send in a request:

```
[{
  "user_id": "861",
  "username": "userA",
  "friend_id": "1270"
},
{
  "user_id": "861",
  "username": "userB",
  "friend_id": "1270"
}]
```

I created the following Test:

```
describe('POST /friends/add', () => {
    it('should return an array of Friend Objects ', (done) => {
        request(app)
            .post('/friend/add')
            .set('auth', token)
            .send([
                {
                    "user_id": authUserId,
                    "username": filteredUsers[0].username,
                    "friend_id": filteredUsers[0].id
                }, {
                    "user_id": authUserId,
                    "username": filteredUsers[2].username,
                    "friend_id": filteredUsers[2].id
                }, {
                    "user_id": authUserId,
                    "username": filteredUsers[3].username,
                    "friend_id": filteredUsers[3].id
                }
            ])
            .expect(200)
            .expect((res) => {
                expect(res.body.email).toBe(email)
            })
            .end((err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    return done(err)
                }
                return done()
            })
    })
})
```

Question:  is `.send([{ }])` is creating the body parameter in the format mentioned above?  an array of objects?

Comment: It depends on the implementation of `send` method of  `request` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API you are using for test querying looks like [SuperTest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest), which under the hood uses [SuperAgent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent). [Here is SuperAgent documentation for `send`](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#post-/-put-requests).

So yes, it will use your array, convert it into JSON and send it in body to your endpoint under test.